# Order of Leaves in Tree (Python)

Tags: python, tree

I am using `treelib` for trees in python. Is there a way (with this or with another library) to represent an order of the children of a node. I would like to add always add to the right of the tree so that the leaves stay in a fixed order (they represent sentences in a text). So the node added first should always be on the left side.
Thank you for your help in advance!

Edit: If one uses .identifier it is represented in the right order. I used the .show() function. The same example from the quickstart guide is then represented with Jane being the third child and not the first one. I wondered if there is a way to change that.

Comment: [It looks what you're asking for is exactly what `treelib` already does.](https://repl.it/repls/TartSoggySoftwareengineer) Can you give us an example that shows what you're talking about?

Comment: (Without looking into the code or docs beyond a quick glance at the quickstart, it's possible that this only works that way on 3.6+, or only if there are fewer than 8 children, or something like that, because it's relying on dict order. But if that's the case, you should be able to easily give us an example where it works differently—if you didn't have such an example, you wouldn't be asking.)